# Dirt is turning into grass

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a baseball field on Minecraft. The texture pack I have is awesome, but there is nothing I can use for a dirt. I tried sand or stained clay but it doesn't look right.

Dirt is the best but I can't keep it to stay dirt next to the grass, obviously. How do I keep dirt next to grass?

Comment: You could try substituting grass with green wool or something.

Comment: Realistically I don't think you can in Vanilla. Carpenter's Blocks might work as I doubt blocks skinned to dirt will grow grass on them, but you'd have to install several mods to get that working and it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 7):

Coarse dirt looks almost identical to dirt, but grass will not grow on it:

[image: Coarse dirt image] [image: Regular dirt image]

(Coarse dirt on the left, normal dirt on the right)

If in survival, you can find it in mega taiga, mesa and savanna biomes. It can also be crafted using normal dirt and gravel:

[image]

Comment: ... Hm.. I remember the was dirt *that actually looked like dirt and not rammaged dirt* that didn't allow for grass to spread onto it. | Any ideas? (Also `dirt:1` is now coarse dirt, not grass-less dirt anymore)

Comment: @aytimothy Can't remember that. Could also set randomtickspeed to 0 I guess, but that'd affect a lot more than grass growing.

Comment: That's why I didn't suggest it. ;)

Comment: FWIW - coarse dirt is also craftable using regular dirt and gravel